# How to develop a menu like wwe.com?

Tags: theme-development, menus, dropdown

I would like to design and develop a WordPress menu like [wwe.com](http://www.wwe.com/)'s menu where it has multiple columns, images and a video section in drop down menus.

I can create a multi-column menu, but I'm not sure how to do images and videos. I also want my client to be able to add/remove videos and images in this menu.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a 'Mega Menu', it allows a full HTML control over dropdown elements of a menu.

There is a free option here - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/ - and CodeCanyon offers a lot premium and fancy mega menu plugins to be purchased.